# Do users have to lose their sense of humour to answer questions on the AskUbuntu Site?

Tags: discussion

I just answered one of my own questions, which I opened a bounty on just this morning.

Rather than just lose the 50 points, I offered it open to the most humorous or correct answer, and that person would get the 50 points I had offered. However, some spoilsport who obviously had a sense of humour by-pass, and edited the question so much that I just answered it myself. Now no one will get the points.

Surely a sense of humour is important? If not, perhaps I should offer all my points for a bounty on a simple question and accept the answer of the person who has the lowest points.

I am very serious with 99.9% of the questions I ask and answer and nobody should be able to edit humour out of existence, If so I would like to down vote their edit, but that's not allowed.

I am not here to collect points, just to help people and myself, to understand and use Ubuntu to the best of my ability.

Comment: Possible question/answer in question http://askubuntu.com/posts/323322/revisions

Comment: That's the one. I wasn't going to point out the question to preserve privicy, but there you go. :)

Comment: You spelled humor wrong. ;-P

Comment: Not in (UK) English, it's humour a bit like colour ;)

Comment: In general, while humor is all well and good, it can be subjective and misunderstood, especially when the readers have different cultural backgrounds and linguistic abilities.

Comment: Take "obviously had a sense of humour by-pass" as an example. I would think that before the "by-pass" said individual had an impaired sense of humor, but after the "by-pass" said individual's humor is restored.

Comment: Oh, and if you have the answer to your question, please just post it. Someone may benefit rather than having to wait till August.

Comment: I did post it it's the only answer after leaving it for 2 days with no replies, I found out what the problem was then, as it wouldn't help anyone and as I had lost the 50 points I had offered, I offered the points to the best or closest answer. Do you believe that anyone would be interested in the fact that the cable I had bought was not of good enough quality? I think not. Any way, my next step is to ask a simple question and offer all of the 1000+ points I have on my account to the person with lowest number of points.

Comment: Meta-close-voters: On main, everything should be an answerable question. That is *not* the case on meta (look around). Please see [the meta help](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-meta) if you are not 100% clear on this. Discussion is allowed here. Questions here don't always have to even ask anything, and there are many questions here explicitly asking for opinions. Closing a question as "primarily opinion based" is *far* less likely to be correct on meta than on main. It seems unlikely that this would have garnered 4 VTCs were it an equally subjective meta question most people *agreed* with.

Comment: I think this meta question has nothing at all to do with Ubuntu or Ask Ubuntu. It would be a better fit in a site dedicated to social studies or human behavior. Something like is this shade of orange better than that shade of orange for some aspect of the web page would be subjective and possibly worth discussing here. But issues of personality?

Comment: I'm actually really surprised that my question has not got more negative points, and I really expected it to be removed. But while it receives comments, negative or positive, I'm happy for it to stay.

Comment: Thanks @vasa1 I never was much good at spelling! :)

Answer (score 7):

I blame the weather; people get extra-grumbly when it's all hot and sweaty and bothersome and things that shouldn't be sticking to each other are. Beurgh.

But on a serious note, when people flag things up as issues and they're correct, we moderators tend to act. You were pushing a question out of the natural fit of the system and out of the boundaries of the standard rules. Bounties are supposed to be meritorious on their technical strengths.

In hindsight, it's easy to see that you weren't doing anything harmful in this instance... But just by allowing it, we would be giving the next person prior-art that they can cite when we next attempted to enforce the rules.

Comment: Now that makes sense. All I wanted to do was add a bit of humour to a stupid mistake I had made, but it all got out of control.

Comment: @SimplySimon You could say "extra points for extra humour" or "extra kudos for a humorous answer". Saying you will give the bounty to the wittiest answer is abusing the bounty system.

Answer (score -3):

you know the humour is so good but perhaps a newbie like me take it offensive.I like it ,but just must be watchful. ;)